# Найти суммы последовательных узлов в бинарном дереве

Tags: python, binary

Есть бинарное дерево поиска и какое-то заданное число S. Нужно найти все монотонные последовательности узлов дерева, сумма значения которых равна S.
Пример.

```
6
/ \
3 8
/ \ / \
2 4 7 10
/ \ / \ / \
1 0 0 5 9 0
```

Для данного дерева если S = 9, то результат 3 последовательности: 6+3, 4+5, 9
Поиск сверху вниз
Моя идея это через поиск в каждом поддереве, но вот не знаю, как перебирать их. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как,например, сравнить 3 и 2, потом 3 и 4, потом 2 и 1.

```
def find(self, value):

    if value == self.root:
        return self.root

    if value < self.root and self.left:
        if self.left
```

Стою на этом моменте уже долго.

Comment: Это не бинарное дерево поиска. В бинарном дереве поиска `0` не может быть правее `1`. Это обычное бинарное дерево.

Comment: Я переделал его в дерево поиска. Но суть остаётся примерно такой же.